# Parse output of Google Cloud command into PHP associative array

Tags: php, parsing, child-process, google-cloud-platform

This is my idea on how to turn Shell exec output in PHP to array output. I just want to share it and get feedback in case there is any better way.

Below is a code example to get [server info from GCE](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list).

```
$shell_command  = "gcloud compute instances list";
$result = shell_exec($shell_command);
//echo "\n$result\n";
$data = explode("\n",$result);
//print_r($data);
$headers = turn_linux_row_to_array($data[0]);
unset($data[0]);
$servers_array = array();
foreach($data as $row){
  $server_data = turn_linux_row_to_array($row,$headers);
   if(!empty($server_data)){
     $servers_array[] = $server_data;
   }
}
//function to move text out put to array
function turn_linux_row_to_array($row,$headers=array()){
$final_data_array = array();
$data_array_position = 0;
$row_length = strlen($row);
$current_word = '';
//echo "\nRow length is :: $row_length\n";
for($i=0; $i<$row_length; $i++){
   $char = substr( $row, $i, 1 );
    if($char != ' '){
     //This is a part of a value
     $current_word .=$char;
    }else{
    if($current_word!=''){
       if(!empty($headers) && isset($headers[$data_array_position]) ){
          $final_data_array[$headers[$data_array_position]] = 
    $current_word;
       }else{
         $final_data_array[] = $current_word;
       }
       $data_array_position++;
   }
   $current_word = '';
 }
}
//print_r($final_data_array);
return $final_data_array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is complicated, and likely buggy.

- If a line does not end in a space character, then the last word on that line will be ignored.
- The output of `gcloud compute instances list` is a table.  For example:

  ```
  NAME                                             ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
  gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-knbs  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1               10.140.0.2   104.155.227.25  RUNNING
  gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-x8cv  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1               10.140.0.3   104.199.226.16  RUNNING
  gke-cluster-asia-eas-default-pool-dc8f484c-z5wv  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1               10.140.0.4   104.199.134.9   RUNNING
  ```

  If the table contains an empty value (such as for the "PREEMPTIBLE" column above), then the `turn_linux_row_to_array()` function will ignore it, resulting in a mismatch between the headers and the values.

I don't recommend trying to improve this code.  Instead, noting that all Google Cloud commands accept a [`--format`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) option, you should choose a format that is easy to parse.  I would recommend replacing the entire code with:

```
$servers = json_decode(shell_exec('gcloud compute instances list --format=json'), true);
```

… to take advantage of [`json_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).  That's it — you're done!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback didn't know on the --foramt=json with GCE will be a great help in the future , this code is more to general purpose usage to transform linux shell out put to array, not a GCE output convertor

Comment: On Code Review, we assume that everything you post is your real code, since it would be impossible (and off-topic) to review hypothetical code. I encourage you to post a separate question about parsing the output of a different Linux command.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplification for parsing headers and removing from array

> ```
> $headers = turn_linux_row_to_array($data[0]);
> unset($data[0]);
> ```

This could be simplified using [array_shift()](http://php.net/array_shift) to pop the first row out of the array of rows, and [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split) to separate header names by 1 or more white space characters:

```
$headers = preg_split('#\s+#',array_shift($data));
```

That way `turn_linux_row_to_array()` doesn't have to handle the headers. Actually, the `for` loop within that method could be replaced with a `foreach`- then the index would be increased automatically.  Additionally, the code in that function could be moved back out to the *foreach* iterating over the rows. The entire code could be simplified like below:

```
$data = explode("\n",$result);
$headers = preg_split('#\s+#',array_shift($data));
foreach($data as $row){
    $server_data = array();
    $words = preg_split('#\s+#',$row);
    foreach($words as $word_position => $word) {
        if (trim($word)) {
            $server_data[$headers[$word_position]] = $word;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($server_data)){
        $servers_array[] = $server_data;
    }
}
```

See a demonstration in [this Playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/3hWMeC6BeNqizhef).

#### Functional approach to iterating over rows

One could also replace the `foreach` loop on the rows with a call to [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map) in order to get the array of words for each row (and pass that to [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter) to eliminate empty rows), though the `use` statement would be required in order to access `$headers` within the callback.

```
$servers_array = array_filter(array_map(function($row) use ($headers) {
    $server_data = array();
    $words = preg_split('#\s+#',$row);
    foreach($words as $word_position => $word) {
        if (trim($word)) {
            $server_data[$headers[$word_position]] = $word;
        }
    }
    return $server_data;
}, $data));
```